# set font weight in titles in a scrartcl

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titles, koma-script

By default, most titles in a KOMA Script article (`scrartcl`) are set in bold (`bx`) weight. For a particular document, I use a special font via

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{MySpecialFont}
```

(this is with lualatex) and would like to have all titles in normal (`m`) weight. That is for the document title, paragraph titles, section titles etc.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Depends highly on the used documentclass. If you are using KOMA, this is very easy, if you are using a standard class, you can use package `titlesec` for the sectioning titles and patch `\maketitle` using package etolbox (or similar) or redefine the title completely. Without more information, this is all guesswork.

Comment: `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}` and `\addtokomafont{title}{\mdseries}`. There are various other instances changable via this interface.

Comment: Are there any news here?